# ASP.NET Core 3.1 How I can run a method from referenced project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, rabbitmq, httpclient

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 WebApi project as the main project and some infrastructure project referenced in the main project like

```
Main Project
 - Domain
 - Common
 - Infrastructure
```

An event raises in Infrastructure (for example from rabbitMQ)
How I can call a method in Main Project?

I used httpclient to call a WebApi Method in Main project but I had to use full address which is not nice to use

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync($"https://localhost:44304/api/test/ddl?id={msg.Id}"))
    {
        string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

In this scenario I have to set https://localhost ... for web api address which is not very good idea I think, is there any way to mention local webapi without full url?

Is there any other solution to call a method in parent project from referenced project?

Comment: Can you call the methods that are executed at that route by the main proj? If all of the methods that do the 'work' are in the main project, that might suggest they should be moved to a lower layer such as common if not the infrastructure layer itself..

Comment: Hi Mertez. Do you know what events are and how to use them? I think this is the answer to your question. Have a look for "c# events example" if you're not sure. Does that help? Regards, Adam.

Comment: @AdamBenson Hey Adam, I know events for sure, but I don't know how to handle events from a referenced class library

Comment: Ah right - so Infrastructure is not yours and you can't put an event in it. I was hoping there would be something you could latch on to - usually there is in a library. You mention that you're making an http call in response to the event, how is that happening if Infrastructure is a black box?

Comment: @AdamBenson Infrastructure is mine, it's in my solution beside the main project and referenced in Main